# Simple Energy Estimate problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I am doing a computation and I need the following inequality (if true)
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty{fv^2 {\mbox{d}}x}\leq \|f\|_{L^2}\|v\|_{L^2}^2,
$$
for any function $v$ and $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. It seems it should hold but I cannot quite use Cauchy-Schwarz or Holder to make it work. If it is true, please provide the argument so I can use it in my following computations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is false. By Basic Hilbert space theory this inequality would imply that $\|v^{2}\| \leq \|v\|^{2}$ and it is easy to see that this is false. [Example $v=I_{(0,\frac  1 2)}$].

Comment: Thanks for the answer!